# Sharing a photo within app wp7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, share, photo

Sharing photos from the "Pictures" app is so simple, is there a way to use the same share structure for another app. Basically I'm making an app that let's you manipulate pictures and I'd like for my users to be able to share to facebook, twitter, etc. For example, when you go to your pictures and press the "share..." menu item, is there a way to use this share task for my app? That is instead of going through all of these sdk's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no API in the current (7.1) SDK to provide sharing of an image. If you don't want to duplicate sharing functionality (I'd suggest you don't) I'd say you've got two options;

1. After you've manipulated the photo allow the user to save it back to their to their `MediaLibrary` (See: [Encoding a JPEG file and Adding It to the Pictures Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769549%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)
    as an example). From here the user can then share the image.
2. Within your application upload the image to an image sharing site, retrieve the link for the uploaded image, and then prompt the user to share the link to the image with the `ShareLinkTask` (See [ShareLinkTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharelinktask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) on MSDN)